# Haskell: How do I get the values of #define-d constants?

Tags: haskell, ffi, cabal, hsc2hs

In a Haskell program, what's the best way to use constants defined in C headers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For this task, [hsc2hs](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/hsc2hs.html) is your friend.

For a simple example, let's get the value of `INT_MAX` from [`limits.h`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limits.h).

```
$ cat >IntMax.hsc
module Main where

#include <limits.h>

c_INT_MAX = #const INT_MAX

main = print c_INT_MAX
```

With hsc2hs, we can `#include` headers and use the values of constants with the `#const` directive.

Instead of building by hand, use Cabal:

```
$ cat >intmax.cabal
Name:          intmax
Version:       0.0
Cabal-Version: >=1.2
Build-Type:    Simple

Executable intmax
  Main-Is: IntMax.hs
  Build-Depends: base
```

Notice that even though the name of the main program is `IntMax.hsc`, the `Main-Is` line points to `IntMax.hs`. When Cabal looks for `IntMax.hs` but finds `IntMax.hsc`, it automatically feeds the latter through hsc2hs as part of the build.

```
$ cabal configure
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring intmax-0.0...

$ cabal build
Prerocessing executables for intmax-0.0...
Building intmax-0.0...
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( dist\build\intmax\intmax-tmp\IntMax.hs, dist\build\intmax\intmax-tmp\Main.o )
Linking dist\build\intmax\intmax.exe ...

$ ./dist/build/intmax/intmax
2147483647
```

Note that you'll want to break up lines with multiple constants. Say you're assembling a bitfield to pass to [FormatMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679351.aspx). You'll want to write it as

```
flags = #const FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM
        .|.
        #const FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS
```

Putting them all on one line will result in syntax errors.

Answer (score 4):

GHC is moving away from `-fvia-c` and towards `-fasm` wherever possible.

One side effect is that your program may be compiled without using any C headers at all, even in `-fvia-c` mode, in order to ensure that the compilation results are functionally identical to GHC in `-fasm` mode.

Thus it is necessary to use `hsc2hs`, `c2hs`, or other preprocessors run *before* GHC compiles sources.

`c2hs` natively supports `enum` constants... it's been a while, but I think something like this is right.

```
#c
enum Foo = { Bar, Baz };
void something(enum Foo foo) {}
#endc

{#enum Foo#}

somethingBar = {#call pure something#} (cFromEnum Bar)
```

`#define`'d constants are a tick trickier.  I've always just copied them inline, or used additional C to transform then into enums or const variables.